# How to stop nodemon debugger on production

Tags: debugging, gruntjs, nodemon

This is my grunt file: (the relevant portion)

```
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                    ext: 'js,html',
                    watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
                }
            }
        },
        'node-inspector': {
            custom: {
                options: {
                    'web-port': 1337,
                    'web-host': 'localhost',
                    'debug-port': 5858,
                    'save-live-edit': true,
                    'no-preload': true,
                    'stack-trace-limit': 50,
                    'hidden': []
                }
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            default: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
            debug: ['nodemon', 'watch', 'node-inspector'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        },
    });

    // Load NPM tasks 
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'concurrent:default']);

    // Debug task.
    grunt.registerTask('debug', ['lint', 'concurrent:debug']);

    // Lint task(s).
    //grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint', 'csslint']);
    grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint']);
```

On my server, when i write this command:

```
NODE ENV=production PORT=80 grunt --force
```

Im having this promped in my console:

[image]

I want no debugger in production, what needs to change?
I tried to remove the nodemon --debug option but with no success,
also i tried to change the debug port to another one in node-inspector, but i dont really initiate the node-inspector in the command above, and what tells him to do the nodemon-dev portion at all?